# Starting a new thread from inside a thread

Tags: java

I have a program which creates a thread to monitor user input. The thread has a `while(true)` loop which continually checks whether or not a certain series of strings has been typed.

Once a certain string has been typed I would like to set off a Timer or start a Thread that executes a piece of code every few seconds or so. The original thread needs to keep going concurrently.

I was wondering how I can do this? I'd like to keep the threads separate in a sense that If one exits the run() method, the other one remains alive and I can still get a reference to it.

Comment: Just curious -- is this a Swing GUI application?

Comment: And yes, it is perfectly OK to start a Thread within a Thread, but you might want to consider using a Thread pool.

Comment: It's not a GUI application. It's actually a server listening for messages. Thanks for the response, I'm going to read up on a Thread pool now

Comment: Using `while(true)` to check whether the user has typed something is a bad idea:  you'll use 100% of a CPU core, just to check the same string millions of times when the user hasn't even pressed another key yet.  Do your check in response to a keystroke event.

Comment: @Wyzard Not if the loop contains a read() or equivalent. The OP hasn't given enough info to determine this.

Comment: I do have blocking code to make sure I don't run into that problem. You are correct for pointing it out though Wyzard as I did leave out some information

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can start new threads inside another thread. They won't depend on the interrupted status of the initial thread.
You can store reference to newly created thread(s) in instance variable